# Alert to enable gps and network , location

Tags: android

I want to test if the gps is enabled and if so to show an alert

```
            protected void createGpsDisabledAlert() {
    AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    builder.setMessage("Your GPS is disabled! Would you like to enable it?");

    builder.setButton("Enable GPS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            showGpsOptions();
        }

    });
    builder.setButton2("Do nothing", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            return;
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}

private void showGpsOptions() {
    Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);

}
```

I did debug and it seems everything ok , i have no error , but the alert does not appear, even if it eneters in method

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a **very resuseful** approach!
Just configure onResume for each activity according its needed resources. This approach going to alert the user to enable resources and provide shortcuts to the resource settings. The user can do nothing still everything is enabled.

UPDATE: http://code.google.com/p/android-resource-checker/

Answer (score 1):

check this code i add the GPS is enabled or disabled in Toast.......

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.*;
import android.location.*;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.*;

public class DirectionsWhereisparty extends Activity {
    double destin_lat = 0, destin_lng = 0;
    double current_lat = 0, current_lng = 0;
    boolean flag = true;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                mlocListener);
    }

    public void go(double c_lat, double c_lng, double d_lat, double d_lng) {

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (b != null) {

            String lat = b.getString("lat");
            String lng = b.getString("lng");

            d_lat = Double.parseDouble(lat);
            d_lng = Double.parseDouble(lng);

            // System.out.println("d_lat " + d_lat);
            // System.out.println("d_lng " + d_lng);

            String Text = "My current location is: " + "Latitude = " + c_lat
                    + "Longitude = " + c_lng;

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                    .parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + c_lat
                            + "   ,  " + c_lng + "&daddr=" + d_lat + "   ,   "
                            + d_lng));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

    {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

            current_lat = loc.getLatitude();
            current_lng = loc.getLongitude();

            if (flag == true) {
                flag = false;
                go(current_lat, current_lng, destin_lat, destin_lng);
            }

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

}
```